# A tearful farewell

Tags: riddle, cipher, imgur-maze

## "Education is the key to success in life, and teachers make a lasting impact on the lives of students. "

This is one of my favourite quotes as quoted by Solomon Ortiz. It highlights the importance of teachers in our life, a topic which is very much ignored in today's world. Yesterday was my last full day in high school and to be honest, it was a tad emotional.
Anyway, Long story cut short, I have decided to send a message to you. (Yes, you puzzling user!)

I have left you with some clues below and it would lead you to the right answer.
And yes, it is a multi-layered Puzzle.

And here's an advice, if you ever get stuck in the puzzle, come back here. The key to solving it lies here.

**CLUES:**

1. Extremely complex and unreal. (1)
2. A neatly arranged pile. (5)
3. Public perception without final two of its three vitals(3)
4. First Two-thirds of a Formal Web.(2)
5. Arrive without your tail(3)
6. They are small, Oddly identical(2)
7. Big Symbolic Victory(1)
8. Alternate Occupation with big tail(2)
9. A sudden pain without a second.(3)

<sub>I feel that a a few of the clues are cryptic-clues, but I am not too sure. So, I avoided the tag.</sub>

Comment: No, they aren't cryptic clues. They don't have independently solvable definitions and wordplay, which leads to the problem you're having here of multiple possible solutions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The first stage leads us fairly clearly to

> i.stack.imgur/(something).png

And here are the clues in total

> Extremely complex and unreal. (1) - **i**(Because i is a part of complex number and an imaginary number iteslf)
>  A neatly arranged pile. (5) - **stack**
>  Public perception without final two of its three vitals(3) - **img**(image without the last two vowels removed)
>  First Two-thirds of a Formal Web.(2) - **ur**(first two of url)
>  Arrive without your tail(3) - **com**(come without e)
>  They are small, Oddly identical(2) - **sm**(oddly-not identical) s and m)
>  Big Symbolic Victory(1) - **V**(V for victory)
>  Alternate Occupation with big tail(2) - **jB**(alternate letters from JOB)
>  A sudden pain without a second.(3) - **png**(pang without letter a)

this leads us to

> [image: Riddle Picture]

Which clues

> **s** (he/she), **f** (f/ans), **W** (who/what/when/where/why), **ps**, **png** (Papau, New Guinea)

The spoiler text is

> ROT 13, "The heading and the body in the final part are differently coded. Don't merge them!"

This brings us to

> [image: Picture Two, Electric Boogaloo]

The title of which is

> A message from Sid (rot13)

While the text decodes to

> Using a Vigenere cipher with key "Education"
>  Sid regretfully informs the one who
>  has reached this far that he won't be
>  able to accept your answer right now.
>  Sid also wishes the site the best
>  for its future as it is becoming
>  increasingly likely that he wont
>  be part of the site in the near future

All credit to [everything going on here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/conversation/a-conversation-about-sid)

Answer (score 6):

Partial answer:

> Extremely complex and unreal. (1)  --> **i**
>  A neatly arranged pile. (5) --> **stack**
>  Public perception without final two of its three vitals(3) --> **img** (Image without final two vowels)
>  First Two-thirds of a Formal Web.(2) --> **ur** (first two letters of url)
>  Arrive without your tail (3) --> **com** (come without the e)
>  They are small, Oddly identical (2) not sure about this, perhaps **11**? (two small odd identical numbers)
>  Big Symbolic Victory (1) not sure about this, perhaps **W**, short for the word Win?
>  Alternate Occupation with big tail (2) not sure about this, perhaps **aO**, taking the most obvious abbreviation of alternate occupation, and making the tail letter big..
>  A sudden pain without a second. (3)  --> **png** (pang without the second letter)

This leads to:

> an image: **i.stack.imgur.com/11WaO.png**, which doesn't work... So, perhaps a slight variation

Comment: I think first two thirds of formal web is 'ww'. first 2 of www.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil no, definitely what it says in Levieux's answer. Look at the structure of what it produces.

Comment: (I don't think cluing that with "Formal Web" makes any sense, mind you, but it's clearly right.)

Comment: I think "big tail" means second letter is capital rather than lowercase, but I could be wrong. I agree with GPR about the symbolic victory and don't really see how it could be anything else. I have no idea whatever what "alternate Occupation" means nor why "Occupation" has a capital letter :-).

Comment: Occupation has a capital letter because I messed up a bit. And GPR is right. None of your other answers are correct.(Apart from the obvious ones)

Comment: Small, Oddly identical (2) could be "dd" as two lowercase identical letters in "oddly"

Comment: @Levieux- You may update your answer with this [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/smVjB.png)

Comment: @Techidiot how did you figure those letters? I can see how it works but not how we were supposed to get it from the clues.. (maybe post a separate answer? not sure of the etiquette)

Comment: @whrrgarbl - I am posting one.

Answer (score 6):

All Credit's to [People here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair) plus a little for myself for formatting an answer :)

Here it goes -

> Extremely complex and unreal. (1) - **i**(Because i is a part of complex number and an imaginary number iteslf)
>  A neatly arranged pile. (5) - **stack**
>  Public perception without final two of its three vitals(3) - **img**(image without the last two vowels removed)
>  First Two-thirds of a Formal Web.(2) - **ur**(first two of url)
>  Arrive without your tail(3) - **com**(come without e)
>  They are small, Oddly identical(2) - **sm**(oddly-not identical) s and m)
>  Big Symbolic Victory(1) - **V**(V for victory)
>  Alternate Occupation with big tail(2) - **jB**(alternate letters from JOB)
>  A sudden pain without a second.(3) - **png**(pang without letter a)

This gives-

> [image]

Decoding the lines once again -

> Adding this could turn a man to a woman - > **s**(Ms. An)
>  Try to look at the leader of all those fans -> **f**(f as first letter)
>  Next is beginning of most questions -> **W**(What when where?)
>  My last two are small extra remarks at the end -> **ps**

This gives - >

> [image]

Which is ->

> N zrffntr ol Fvq
>  Wlx tezzsgjxfny bvtbvpm vhx wbr aki
>  jal zsngkyf taqg seu njam ps jsq'n de
>  tjzr xr uecxxh lsxl cnlese vlajt gwk.
>  Fmg unsh ewflhm vhx awgi wbg bxah
>  ssu cvs ychhvh uu im qg oifioigo
>  waguycsbvuyc ocmeeg huew bg whv'h
>  oi sutt hn hui vcve bv hui qycr ychhvh.

Then ->

> Applying Vignere to it with EDUCATION as key gives:
>  ***Sid regretfully informs the one who
>
>  has reached this far that he won't be
>
>  able to accept your answer right now.
>
>  Sid also wishes the site the best
>
>  for its future as it is becoming
>
>  increasingly likely that he won't
>
>  be part of the site in the near future.***

And..

> Rot-13 to the title *N zrffntr ol Fvq* gives **"A message by Sid "**